# Use C# DataView.RowFilter Property on a function's argument of string type

Tags: c#

Is there a way to use the `Rowfilter` property of `DataView` on the following `string` variable?

```
public DataTable FilterByLatestDate(DataTable tbl, string date_asof)
    {
        DataView latest = tbl.DefaultView;
        //latest.RowFilter = "[date]= '" + date_asof + "'"  ; // 
        //latest.RowFilter = string.Format("[date]= '{0}'", date_asof); // alternative to messing around with quotes

DataTable last_tbl = latest.ToTable();

return last_tbl;
}
```

*Ps: I am **only** interested in suggestions involving `.Rowfilter`*

Best

Comment: Or use C# 6.0 syntax and just write `$"[date]=#{date_asof}#"`.

Comment: still with `# 4.0`, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a Date in a RowFilter the quoting characted to use is the # symbol

```
latest.RowFilter = "[date]= #" + date_asof + "#"  ;
```

However the RowFilter property accepts a string and thus when you use a Date for the filter the variable should be expressed in format as "MM/dd/yyyy". 
So if your string `date_asof` is not in this format then this code could not work correctly.

I suggest you to pass a DateTime to your function and format it with

```
public DataTable FilterByLatestDate(DataTable tbl, DateTime date_asof)
{
    DataView latest = tbl.DefaultView;
    latest.RowFilter = "[date]= #" + date_asof.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "#";
    return latest.ToTable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip in using  the `#` symbol. `date_asof`, by default, has been formatted on `M/dd/yyyy`. However I still encounter a SyntaxErrorException with the #.

Comment: Are you able to debug this code? If yes then put a breakpoint on the RowFilter line and check the exact text passed to the RowFilter property. I have just tested code similar to the above one and no Syntax error

Comment: Ex-ante ("") naturally. Ex-post:`The expression contains invalid date constant '##'`

Comment: This seems that your date_asof is empty?

Comment: it's unlikely as `date_asof` is called by another method whose return value value has been checked. furthermore i've put it in a public property and checked it before posting.

Comment: However the two symbols "##" could be produced only with "#" + "" + "#". By the way tested with an empty string and got exactly the same exception. To have a final check try to use temporarily a constant of a known existing date and check if there is no more exception.

Comment: Right with a previous comment , Steve.  while hard-coding `date_asof`, things get sorted (no syntax exception) reinforcing your idea that `date_asof` might be empty although i still see a return value from the public property in which it is stored. will keep looping through... but many thanks with the #symbol (key)